# Ошибка при преобразовании даты, и времени из строки

Tags: delphi

При преобразовании даты, и времени из строки получаю ошибку
"**'09:00 21.02.2020' is not a valid date and time.**"

```
function START: TDateTime;
var
  FS: TFormatSettings;
begin
  FS := TFormatSettings.Create;
  FS.DateSeparator := '.';
  FS.ShortDateFormat := 'DD.MM.YYYY';
  FS.TimeSeparator := ':';
  FS.ShortTimeFormat := 'HH:NN';
  Result := StrToDateTime('09:00 21.02.2020', FS);
end;
```

В чем может быть проблема?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Функция `StrToDateTime` ожидает, что вначале идёт дата, а потом время. Об этом написано в SysUtils.pas перед описанием функции:

```
{ StrToDateTime converts the given string to a date and time value. The
  string must contain a date optionally followed by a time. The date and
  time parts of the string must follow the formats described for the
  StrToDate and StrToTime functions. }

function StrToDateTime(const S: string): TDateTime; overload; inline;
function StrToDateTime(const S: string; const AFormatSettings: TFormatSettings): TDateTime; overload;
```

Соответственно, вызывать надо вот так:

```
Result := StrToDateTime('21.02.2020 09:00', FS);
```

Либо, надо парсить строку и конвертировать время и дату отдельно, функциями `StrToTime` и `StrToDate`.

Comment: Спс, а как быть с моей строкой?

Comment: @LEGENDED Я же написал - парсить и конвертировать отдельно. Можете воспользоваться функцией [SplitString](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Rio/en/System.StrUtils.SplitString), указав пробел, в качестве разделителя.